# Reclaim JVM Committed Memory when using G1GC to scale down system

Tags: java, jvm

I am running dropwizard REST Applications on AWS ECS (Docker Containers).
Application sizes vary from 512MiB, 1/4/8 GiB.
I am using G1GC.

Under high load,
JVM used heap increases (with sawtooth pattern).
Hence, the committed memory of JVM increases as well.

When the load on application decreases back to idle (in my test, there is no load at all), the JVM committed memory is not released.
Used heap has sawtooth pattern, but the spikes are much larger (My guess is JVM is using more heap memory before young garbage collection triggers as committed memory exists).

ECS task (~kubernetes pod) memory usage considers JVM committed memory to calculate used memory.

I want JVM to release the committed memory after the spike in load, so that ECS task memory utilization decreases, thereby we can scale down our system based on ECS-Task memory usage metric.

I am trying to use -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio to ensure memory is released, but this only works during full GC cycle, which doesn't get triggered (unless I manually trigger it).
I think G1GC tried to prevent full GC.

My question is, how can I trigger full GC or how can I ensure committed memory is released back so that my system can be scaled down based on memory usage metric.

Update:
May be my solution is to trigger Full GC via System.gc() at the time when there's no traffic on my system.
I was hoping to find a JVM argument that can trigger GC OR reduce claimed heap when there's excessive heap reserved.

Its weird that JVM doesn't give back memory, its big disadvantage for autoscaling.

[image]

Comment: What is JDK version?

Comment: We are using `eclipse-temurin:11.0.21_9-jre`

Answer (score 0):

You are running JDK 11.
Uncommit of unused heap with G1 GC has been implemented in JDK 12.

See https://openjdk.org/jeps/346